# what if LocationListener.onLocationChanged is not called?

Tags: android, google-play-services

In my android app, I am making use of google play's location services for determining device location.So I am implementing com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener's onLocationChanged method. But based on device's location settings, it is very much possible that this method is not even called.For eg, if user has set 'Device Only' option then only GPS based location access is available,and if user is indoor GPS wont work and onLocationChanged() is not called.

**I want to know how to come to know of this at run time so that alternate action can be suggested to user?**

Comment: so you to know if the user is indoor or outdoor ?

Comment: no....user can use app anywhere,indoor or outdoor.

Comment: you can always send a delayed message to see if the location wasn't received and then display the user some message like 'unable to get the current location'.

Comment: Meh, how to approach for that...any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

From the [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) itself, `LocationListener` is used for receiving notifications from the LocationManager when the location has changed. These methods are called if the `LocationListener` has been registered with the location manager service using the `requestLocationUpdates(String, long, float, LocationListener)` method.

Also check this [blog](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/12/25/understanding-locationlistener-android/) to understand more about `LocationListener` in Android. It also explains here the status and behavior of a GPS and some sample code that serve as a guide for you. I hope it helps you to know more about `LocationListener`